# Trying to rewrite url in .htaccess but not changing

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite my URL http://localhost/jainvidhya/register.php?role=admin to http://localhost/jainvidhya/register/admin, but the following code doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.localhost [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/jainvidhya/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^register/(.*)/$ register.php?role=$1&%1
```

I have also tried restarting my server and clearing browsing history

Answer (score 0):

So first you can either drop the `RewriteBase /` or set it to the **jainvidhya** subdir.

```
RewriteBase /jainvidhya
```

Also the last RewriteRule tries to match an ending / (slash) sign in the URL, so you may want to put that optional like this:

```
RewriteRule ^register/(.*)/?$ register.php?role=$1&%1
```

Or better try to specify a proper alphanumeric rexexp like this:

```
RewriteRule ^register/([^/w]+)/?$ register.php?role=$1&%1
```

Comment: You mean I should try: `RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^register/?$    register.php    [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^register/([^/w]+)/?$ register.php?role=$1&%1`?